# Criterium to extending the interval of definition of an ODE solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We have F: $U\to\mathbb{R}^{d}$ continuous. Suppose $\gamma$ is solution defined on (a,b).
I want to prove that:

"If there is a sequence $\ ({t_{n}})$ and y $\in$ $U$ s.t. $(\ {t_{n}},\gamma({t_{n}}))\to (b,y) \in U$, then we can extend the solution to some interval (a,b+$\epsilon$)."

By Peano´s Theorem, there´s a solution $\beta$ defined in some interval (b-$\epsilon$,b+$\epsilon$) of x'=F(t,x) s.t. $\beta(b)=y$.
So I think we could extend the solution to $\gamma(t)$, for t $\in$ (a,b), y if t=b and $\beta(t)$ in (b,b+$\epsilon$).
But i dont know why would this actually be class $ c^{1}$.
Does this actually imply that $\exists$ $ lim_{t\to b} ({\gamma({t})})$?

Comment: Yes, the first limit on the sequences $t_n$ suggests that the solution could be "interesting" (oscillating etc.) close to $b$. When you show that $\beta$ has to be the same as $\gamma$ on $(b-ϵ,b)$, then you have also shown that, actually, $\gamma$ is "boring" on that interval, with the consequence that the function limit exists. As both of the patches are $C^1$, also the extended solution is $C^1$.

Comment: Wait, so $\beta$ has to coincide with $\gamma$ on (b-$\epsilon$,b) even without the uniqueness property? (we don´t necessarily have it because F is only contionuous)

Comment: You get a local solution around $(b,y_b)$ with interval radius $ϵ$. Then you can extend this construction to the initial points $(t_n,γ(t_n))$ where $|t_n-b|\leϵ/3$. Due to the established properties this results in local solutions that have a radius of the domain of at least $2ϵ/3$, which guarantees an extended domain to $b+ϵ/3$. There is no guarantee that any of these additional solutions passes through $(b,y)$. But among all the admissible local solutions you can find a converging sequence over $[b,b+ϵ/3]$ where the limit at $b$ is $y$. Now consider the integral equation to show $C^1$.